# WordPress Reading Settings

Tags: admin-ui

I find the default reading settings a bit confusing. The way it is shown looks like changes that can be performed all concern the front page / index page and no other page.

Meaning when selecting to show a static page as the front page it will show the about page and content on the front page **as well as** under that the posts from the chosen page, in this case the `sample page`. So two content sources that get displayed on the front page under each other.

[image]

Changing the `Posts page` means that the page chosen in the pull down menu is the one where the latest or all posts **will be shown under**.

This page with posts will not be added to the static front page as the UI suggest under `Front page displays`.

In order to provide better UX and UI for the users I like to change this section to something like this.

[image]

I want to make changes as to how these settings appear and add a written description to it in the dashboard. How do I go about this please? What Wordpress hooks do I need to change that section of the dashboard please?

edit:
I found this on the codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Admin_Screen_Reference#Settings.

> Some hooks require that the developer append a screen id to the hook
>   name. The reasoning for this is that you often need to target specific
>   admin screens with your hooks, and this allows you that necessary
>   level of control.

And further down I find the ID being `Reading Settings options-reading.php options-reading`. So is there really no hook that can be used with this ID to makes changes to that file without touching WP core? How could I write a plugin that changes the options-reading.php file?

[This](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16379) might be of interest, it seems the UI of this section has been an active topic for years.

Comment: There aren’t any filters for modifying this screen. If you look at wp-admin/options-reading.php you can see that it’s all basically hard-coded.

Comment: try added_option or add_option_{$option} hooks... you'll need to find the option name https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/added_option/